# How do you create a Serial Workflow in SharePoint Designer?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I am new to using workflows in SharePoint 2010, and am wondering how to create a serial workflow from scratch in SharePoint Designer (SPD) 2010.  I have a client that would like an approval workflow created for his executives' approval documents, and I do not know where to begin.
I have made large "auto-populate" workflows in SPD 2010 before but do not know what I am doing with approval workflows.  The part I am still stumped on is how to create the automatic e-mails to folks as soon as it has been created, approved or rejected by the previous individual.  Scouring the internet has not provided the black and white that I need.

Any assistance is very much appreciated!

Comment: Trying looking at the "Start Approval Workflow" action for 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding Approval workflow , it already exists as built in and no need to create it using SharePoint Designer else you have special requirements

To create approval workflow on library or list

- Open List from the above ribbon > click on list Tab > click workflow > add workflow >

[image]

- Select Publishing workflow

[image]

- Check when the workflow will start on item added or updated.

[image]

- Set your approvals as serial

[image]

If you have special requirment and you want to do it from scratch , you should check this to create it from scratch in SharePoint designer

- http://plexhosted.com/billing/knowledgebase/226/How-to-create-a-simple-approval-workflow-in-SharePoint-Designer.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfGDBzQvAwI

Comment: Dear @Mumford451 I am also here if you need more clarification

Comment: I am still new to StackExchange but I have seen your name all over these SharePoint questions.  Thank you for your answer, I should have clarified further.  The reason I would like to learn how to build them from scratch is because my client does have a multitude of special requirements.  I appreciate the info and help!

Comment: check this to create it from scratch in SharePoint designer and if you need any help I am here :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfGDBzQvAwI  http://plexhosted.com/billing/knowledgebase/226/How-to-create-a-simple-approval-workflow-in-SharePoint-Designer.html

Comment: Thank you again @M.Qassas I was unable to vote it useful because I am new BUT I will take all of this information and mark it as answered.